# bootstrap radio button and collapse works only partly

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a radio button group together with collapse functionality in my bootstrapped website. I want to have 3 buttons and only one button / div active at any given time. I got it to work partly, but not completely.

When I select the first radio button it shows me the first div correctly. If I move to the 2nd div it works great too. If I move back to the 1st div that also shows. But then - if I move to the 3rd button it shows the 3rd div, but if I then go back to the 1st button the 1st div does not show anymore. From that point on I can only show div2 and div3.

Here's what I did.

I created the radio button group as follows:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" onclick="showdiv(1);">Save as PDF</button>
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" onclick="showdiv(2);">Simple API</button>
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" onclick="showdiv(3);">Advanced API</button>
</div>
```

Then I created three divs as below:

```
<div id="div1" class="row pricing collapse">
     .....
</div>
<div id="div2" class="row pricing collapse">
     .....
</div>
<div id="div3" class="row pricing collapse">
     .....
</div>
```

The javascript that I created to show a given div is as follows:

```
function showdivold(divnr) {
  for (var i=1;i<=3;i++)
  {
    if (i==divnr)
    {
      $('#div'+i).collapse('show');
    }
    else
    {
      $('#div'+i).collapse('hide');
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I use jquery1.8.3 and bootstrap js.

Another problem is that I can't seem to get the default state of the 1st radio button to be set to 'pressed'.

Comment: Any [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?  Is this what you are after?  I used Bootstrap 2.3.1 and JQuery 1.9.1.  Hope latest versions are not issues for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="btn-group nav nav-tabs" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
        <button class="btn btn-large" href="#div1" data-toggle="tab">Save as PDF</button>
        <button class="btn btn-large" href="#div2" data-toggle="tab">Simple API</button>
        <button class="btn btn-large" href="#div3" data-toggle="tab">Advanced API</button>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="div1" class="tab-pane active">
             <p>div #1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="div2" class="tab-pane">
             <p>div #2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="div3" class="tab-pane">
             <p>div #3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```